# Is there a single word for the meaning of the phrase "unlikely but true"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing a formal letter and I am looking for a single word that represents or means "unlikely but true."

The context is that I want to reference a story in a book written by my recipient that fits this description of "unlikely but true."

Comment: Depending on the sentence, you might be able to use *incredible / unbelievable*. Please [edit] to include a sample sentence for context.

Comment: Unbelievable would work but I was looking for something less common.

Comment: It would help for you to [edit] your question to include the words you’ve considered and explain why each isn’t suitable.

Comment: Perhaps **fantastic** (the recipient knows the story is true).

Answer (score 1):

**Improbable** carries this sense, but needs to be used judiciously as it is of course not the default sense:

> ... [also]
>
> unlikely but real or true
>
> - *The team made an improbable comeback*.

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/improbable)]

> - *Christina Strutt is seated at her battered kitchen table, wearing an improbable pink floral pinafore ...*

[[The Times: Interiors; 2010](https://www.thetimes.co.uk/article/interiors-a-house-after-her-own-fashion-gwf0v95qw50)]

Answer (score 0):

[Paradoxical](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/paradoxical#English). (The definition given in the Wiktionary entry doesn't have quite this meaning, but if you look at its entry for [paradox](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/paradox), or indeed at the examples it gives for "paradoxical", you will see that it matches what you are looking for. I shall have a look at improving this).

Comment: Paradoxes are a subset of what the OP is asking about. Many unlikely things (i.e. things of antecedently low probability) are not paradoxical (i.e. they don't seem absurd).